# How to change the color of multiple objects of the same color all at once?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cs5

I have a design that has MANY objects. All objects are one of five different colors. I want to change all the objects that are a peach color to a different color all together. To find all of these objects, select them, then change them would take forever.

Is there a way to select one of the peach objects and tell Illustrator CS5 to find all of the other peach objects and change them all to my new color?

Comment: In the future, assuming you're making it all from scratch, you might want to use [Global swatches](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/using-creating-swatches.html).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Option 1.

If you want to change one specific color to another specific color.

- Select one object of the color you want to change
- **Select → Same → Fill Color**
- Change the fill to your desired new color

### Option 2.

If you want to change multiple colors.

- Select All (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>) (or select the parts of your artwork you want to change)
- **View → Hide Edges** or (<kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>) *This step isn't necessary, but makes viewing artwork in the next step easier*
- **Edit → Edit Colors → Recolor Artwork...** (or there is a Recolor Artwork button in the control panel that looks like a color wheel)

[image: Adobe Illustrator Recolor Artwork]

You can learn more about Illustrator's Recolor Artwork here:

- [Adobe Illustrator Tutorials - Recolor Artwork](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/how-to/illustrator-recoloring-artwork.html)